# Filetype icon sets

Tags: windows, icons, file-types

Even though I'm into customizing windows to be quite pretty, this is more of a usability issue.

Can anyone recommend a filetype icon pack, so one could tell which files he is looking at at a glance while browsing folders. I'm especially interested in text file differentiation - .php from .phtml, from .ini etc.

Two media players I use - KMPlayer and AIMP2 assign pretty and informative icons to their respective filenames themselves and I'd like more such functionality...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kinda like these? http://customize.org/icons/43393

Comment: this one looks better http://www.zeusboxstudio.com/blog/free-filetypes-icons